# push notifications in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I've implement a Project to send push notifications to a Windows phone application.
The notification coming succesfully in the emulator or i'm running the app to send to a different emulator and the app to receive to another emulator and it Works fine.
The problem is that the notification is not coming to the telephone device.
Is there a restriction or any other issue to check?

Comment: is that any sample you followed? are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: Yes from video http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=l_OHDmYCuHc from the emulator it's OK, but is not working on the device

Comment: @Kulasangar did you ever get this problem sorted, I'm having the same trouble?

Comment: No I didn't find anything yet, I left that project for now

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should set the variable `channelname` via `ToastSampleChannel`, so, the field `private const String ChannelName = "MyChannel"` should be changed accordingly.

`private const String ChannelName = "ToastSampleChannel"`